# Mongo find timestamps in a array, between two dates

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, date

I have documents with a array property `timestamps` as seen in the document below. I wish to find all documents with timestamps between two dates. My find query looks as follow:

```
    $subset = $db->col->find(
            array( 
                'timestamps'=> array(
                    '$elemMatch'=> array(
                        '$gte'=> new MongoDate(strtotime('2016-05-25 13:00:00')),
                        '$lte'=> new MongoDate(strtotime('2016-05-25 14:00:00'))
                    )
                )
            )
    );
```

But it does not return the expected documents. I tried to Google and search StackOverflow for answer but I cannot find anything explaining how to search for timestamps in a array, between two dates.

**EDIT:**

It seems the problem lies with PHP because the same Python query works:

```
import datetime
f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
c = db.col.find({
        'timestamps': {
            '$elemMatch': {
                '$gte': datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-05-25 13:00:00', f),
                '$lte': datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-05-25 14:00:00', f)
            }
        }
    })
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
    "month": {
        "$date": 1464134400000
    }, 
    "timestamps": [
        {
            "$date": 1464181803000
        }, 
        {
            "$date": 1464182103000
        }, 
        {
            "$date": 1464182403000
        }, 
        {
            "$date": 1464183003000
        }, 
        {
            "$date": 1464183603000
        }, 
        {
            "$date": 1464184203000
        }, 
        {
            "$date": 1464184803000
        }, 
        {
            "$date": 1464185403000
        }, 
        {
            "$date": 1464186003000
        }
    ], 
    "status_history": [
        1, 
        1, 
        1, 
        0, 
        1, 
        1, 
        1, 
        0, 
        1
    ], 
    "_id": 12345
}
```

I had a look at [find in array between dates in mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990948/find-in-array-between-dates-in-mongo) and [Get data between two dates mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743642/get-data-between-two-dates-mongo).

Answer (score 0):

It was a timezone issue. I created a `DateTime` and set the timezone to `Etc/GMT` and the expected data returned correctly.

```
$gte = new MongoDate (new DateTime( '2016-05-25 13:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'Etc/GMT' )));
$lte = new MongoDate (new DateTime( '2016-05-25 14:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'Etc/GMT' )));
```